# Keeping headers as `project` in Xcode framework

Tags: objective-c, xcode, frameworks, header

I'm making an Xcode framework, and I have one public header which accesses a bunch of project headers. But when I import the framework in another project, it throws errors that it can't find the header files that are project. I have referenced objects from the project headers in the public header. How do I keep those headers project but still use the objects from them in the public header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the public header file use @class to include other interfaces and use #import in the implementation file (.m).

Using @class informs the compiler that the indicated class exists but the compiler will not require it's implementation.