# Xcode project complains about missing files if a linked framework contains private headers

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, gcc, header, private

My problem is this:

- My framework contains public and private headers - the public headers import private headers **in the framework**
- My app that links against this framework imports public headers

Now when I compile it, Xcode complains about missing files (the private headers that are indirectly imported via the frameworks public headers). I read somewhere on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975907/keeping-headers-as-project-in-xcode-framework) that I should do this:

"In the public header file use @class to include other interfaces and use #import in the implementation file (.m)."

I find this solution pretty unsatisfying - you have to use it for circular dependencies, too. Is there any better way to keep my headers private?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you are trying to accomplish.  What is "unsatisfying" about the forward-declaration approach?

Comment: I find it unsatisfying that I have to differentiate between public and private headers in the source itself, instead of just being able to set it in the target configuration.
If I move a private header to public later, I have to "clean up" the code afterwards - which may lead to "out-of-sync" issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get about circular references use the @class directive in the header and the #import in the source file.

In OtherClass.h:

```
@class MyClass;
@interface OtherClass
{
    MyClass *myInstance;
}
@end
```

In OtherClass.m:

```
#import "OtherClass.h"
#import "MyClass.h"
@implement OtherClass
@end
```

In MyClass.h:

```
@class OtherClass;
@interface MyClass
{
    OtherClass *otherInstance;
}
@end
```

In MyClass.m:

```
#import "MyClass.h"
#import "OtherClass.h"
@implement MyClass
@end
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate example, but this @class declaration is exactly what I find unsatisfying (see comment above)

Comment: Don't get me wrong, this is a good and valid solution, but I was asking for a "cleaner" solution than this - or if there is any :)

Comment: @class is as clean as it gets - in fact that keyword is used mainly to prevent or resolve circular import situations. Same with "class" in C++.